# read hash parameter in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, hash

me jQuery generate url:

```
location.hash = "parameter1=DEF&parameter2=XYZ";
//www.example.com#parameter1=DEF&parameter2=XYZ
```

How to read this **parameter1** and **parameter2** in PHP

Comment: `location.hash` is available at client-side, not server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript is client-side and your PHP is server-side, so it's not possible.

You should rethink your application or use *Ajax* to send data from Javascript to PHP: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I want to create a dynamic filter. After click the change content without loading page, and this information can also logged in the URL.

Comment: @IFun - The "hash" part of a url isn't sent to the server at all, so your approach is flawed.... why not send parameter1 and parameter2 as post vars using a standard Ajax request?

Comment: No problem. You can accept this answer if you think it's the way you have to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can by using `parse_url`

For e.g

```
$url = 'http://google.com#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));
```

Will give you

```
[fragment] = anchor
```

Comment: Except that web browsers don't send anything after the hash to the webserver